# CPAN Perl Module for parsing a PDF file

Tags: perl, cpan

I want to parse a pdf file and extract some content from it. Can anyone please list out any specific perl module ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try looking at

[CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/)

or

[PDF::API3](http://search.cpan.org/~otto/PDF-API3-3.001/)

If you're trying to parse text from the document then it may not be practical. From CAM::PDF::Text

> This module attempts to extract sequential text from a PDF page. This
>   is not a robust process, as PDF text is graphically laid out in
>   arbitrary order. This module uses a few heuristics to try to guess
>   what text goes next to what other text, but may be fooled easily by,
>   say, subscripts, non-horizontal text, changes in font, form fields
>   etc.